# How to group data classes based on 300 variables?

Tags: clustering

I have a data file with thousands of records described by 300 variables. These records belong to 12 different classes. I want to know which classes are the most similar (based on the 300 variables) so that I can group them (I want to make 3 or 4 classes out of the 12 original classes).

I think a good approach could be to calculate the distance between the classes, based on the 300 variables, and then group the classes based on the shortest distance. But I don't know how I could do that practically and where to start. I am using Python or R.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are all your variables numerical ? If so, are they categorical, ordinal, or continuous ?

Comment: All variables are numerical and continuous (mid-infrared wavelengths values)

Comment: What you want is a similarity between classes. You can compute similarity between classes using the centroids, but that's maybe too approximate.
Have you tried k-means with 3 or 4 classes?
Another worthy option is the notion of distribution discrepancy: MMD, Wasserstein etc. The Wasserstein metric is very simple to compute if your data is approximately Gaussian !

Comment: Also if you wish to compare classes up to a translation (class mean) and rotation (class covariance) you can use Procrustes analysis.

Comment: I'll post some examples with python using synthetic data tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, what I want is actually assess the similarity between classes (based on the 300 variables) so that I can group the classes that are most similar.

Comment: As your question is fairly general I've provided code and concepts for two methods. You can also use k-means, DBSCAN , ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer supposes you have a basic knowledge of python3, and that for each of the 12 classes you have enough samples to compute representative summary statistics (a mean or covariance on 3 or 10 points does not make much sense).

I'll use randomly generated data without much structure, you'll have to reproduce the experiments on your data. Here I assume your data is a numpy array
$$\mathbf{X} = \left[ \mathrm{x}_1\; \mathrm{x}_2\;\dots\;\mathrm{x}_n\right]^T$$
of shape $(n,p)$ where $n$ is the number of samples and $p=300$ the number of variables. A row $i$ is a vector $\mathrm{x}_i$ with 300 dimensions.
You also have a label array $\ell = \left[\ell_1\;\ell_2\;\dots\;\ell_n\right]$ of shape $(n,)$ which I will call $\texttt{labels}$ in the python code. I assume $\mathbf{X}$ and $\ell$ are sorted in the same order, namely the $i$-th row $\mathrm{x}_i$ has label $\ell_i$

## Eyeballing based on projections

Project your data $\mathbf{X}$ into a two-dimensional object using, for example, t-SNE. This can be done via scikit-learn using the following snippet:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE

# reduce using t-SNE
tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=0)
projs = tsne.fit_transform(X)

# plot
colors = [plt.cm.tab20.colors[i] for i in labels]
plt.scatter(projs[:,0], projs[:,1], c=colors)
plt.show()
```

In my case, the result is not very helpful as my data is quite random, here it is anyway:

[image: tsne_projs]

If you spot classes, say $C_i$ and $C_j$ which are grouped together in the projected plot, you may assume the datapoints belong to a common class $\tilde{C}$. In my case, merging red-orange-green and brown-grey-purple seems interesting.

## Basic: Comparing centroids

### Idea

A basic approach would be to compute the centroids $\hat{\mu}_k$ of each class $C_k$:
$$ \hat{\mu}_k = \dfrac{1}{\lvert C_k\rvert}\sum_{i\in C_k}\mathrm{x}_i$$
where $\lvert C_k\rvert$ is the number of samples in class $k$.

We then group together classes with similar centroids, namely you set a threshold $\delta > 0$ and decide to merge classes $C_i$ and $C_j$ together if $ \lVert{\hat{\mu}_i - \hat{\mu}_j}\rVert < \delta$, with $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ being either the $l_1, l_2$ or $l_\infty$ norms.

### Code

The centroids can be computed using numpy masks, for example

```py
centroids = []
ulabels = np.unique(labels)

for l in ulabels:
    centroid = X[labels == l].mean(axis=0)
    centroids.append(centroid)
```

Then a non optimal way to compute the centroid similarities $\lVert\hat{\mu}_i - \hat{\mu}_j\rVert$ would be

```py
distances = np.array([[np.linalg.norm(mu_i - mu_j) for mu_i in centroids] for mu_j in centroids])
```

This gives you a similarity matrix, which you can plot using e.g. seaborn's heatmap

```py
import seaborn as sns

sns.heatmap(distances, linewidth=2, alpha=0.8, cmap="YlGnBu" )
plt.show()
```

In my case, this gives

[image: centroid_dists]

And you can set delta in an ad-hoc fashion (in my case $\delta = 0.5$) to get some results. In my case, it recommends to merge classes $2,4,5,6,7$ together and classes $9,10,11$ together, leaving only 6 classes (as $0,1,3,8$ aren't similar to any other class).

## Wasserstein similarity for gaussians

### Idea

If your data for each class $C_i$ is approximately gaussian $\mathcal{N}(\mu_i, \Sigma_i)$, the Wasserstein-2 similarity between the two classes $C_i, C_j$ is defined as

$$ W_2(C_i,C_j) = \lVert\mu_i - \mu_j \rVert_2^2+ \mathrm{Tr}\left[\Sigma_i + \Sigma_j - 2\left(\Sigma_j^{1/2}\Sigma_i\Sigma_j^{{1/2}}\right)^{1/2}\,\right]$$

Where $\mathrm{Tr}[\cdot]$ is the trace of the matrix. This expression **simplifies to the centroid similarity** if you assume the variables have the same diagonal covariance $\Sigma_i = \Sigma_j = \sigma^2\mathbf{I}$. Therefore our basic centroid method makes important assumptions.

We can make the model slightly more powerful by assuming the covariances are diagonal $\sigma_i^2\mathbf{I}$, the trace term then becomes $p(\sigma_i^2 + \sigma_j^2 - 2\sigma_i\sigma_j)$ where $p$ is the number of variables (here 300). This is a sort of "variance dot product" which measures the similarity of the two variances $\sigma_i, \sigma_j$.

We can again make the model more powerful by estimating the covariance from the data, using
$$ \widehat{\Sigma}_k = \dfrac{1}{\lvert C_k \rvert -1}\sum_{i\in C_k} (\mathrm{x}_i - \hat{\mu}_k)(\mathrm{x}_i - \hat{\mu}_k)^T$$
with as before our centroid $\hat{\mu}_k$ for class $k$. Once the convariances for each class are estimated, just plug them in the formula for $W_2(C_i,C_j)$ to estimate class similarity !

### Code

We know how to compute centroids already. If we assume all the covariances are diagonal of the form $\sigma_i^2\mathbf{I}$ then once we know the class, the dimensions have the same variance, therefore we can estimate $\sigma_i^2$ as

```py
ulabels = np.unique(labels)

sigmas = []
centroids = []
for l in ulabels:
    centroid = X[labels == l].mean(axis=0)
    X_l_centered = X[labels == l] - centroid
    sigma = (X_l_centered ** 2).sum() / (X_l_centered.shape[0] - 1)
    sigmas.append(sigma)
    centroids.append(centroid)
```

And then the wassersteins using some helper function

```py
def wass_gauss(mu1,mu2, sq_sig1, sq_sig2):
    return np.linalg.norm(mu1-mu2)**2 + len(mu1)*(sq_sig1 + sq_sig2 - 2*np.sqrt(sq_sig1)*np.sqrt(sq_sig2))
```

In a list comprehension like before:

```py
wassgauss_dists = np.array([[wass_gauss(mu_i,mu_j, sq_sig_i, sq_sig_j)
                                 for mu_i,sq_sig_i in zip(centroids, sq_sigmas)]
                                    for mu_j,sq_sig_j in zip(centroids, sq_sigmas)])
```

You can plot a heatmap again, set a threshold $\delta$ again, etc.
My results for this wasserstein gaussian simplified case is (by setting $\delta = 50$) that one should merge $0,11$ together and $4,5$ together.

I'll leave you the more general case which isn't that complex.

## Wasserstein and MMD

If you assume nothing about your data, you can still keep the idea of similarity between classes $C_i, C_j$ and use more powerful/general tools. A good package is the [geomloss](https://www.kernel-operations.io/geomloss/) package, which makes things very easy! If you need help with this, post a new question and I'll gladly answer.

## Clustering algorithms

You can also use well known clustering algorithms such as [k-means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) and [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN). They both have an implementation within scikit-learn.

Comment: Amazing...this is what I was looking for, thank you!